# Ao escrever no input o texto começa no meio em vez do começo

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Ao escrever no input o texto começa no meio em vez do começo. Como faço para alterar? Ja alterei o padding mas o texto permanece iniciado no meio.

Imagem de exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    elevation: (0),
    backgroundColor: Colors.grey[50],
    leading: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, size: 40),
      color: Colors.grey[600],
      onPressed: () {},
    ),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25, 15, 220, 50),
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
          child: Text(
            "Cadastro",
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 36,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.grey[600]),
          ),
        ),
        Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50, 10, 50, 10),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text("Nome",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 17,
                )),
          )
        ]),
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(),
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50, 10, 50, 10),
          child: TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50, 38, 50, 10),
              filled: true,
              fillColor: Colors.white,
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50, 10, 50, 10),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text("E-mail",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 17,
                )),
          )
        ]),
```

Comment: Cara no TextFormField vc está colocando 38 de padding, não seria isso?

Answer (score 1):

O seu problema é na questão o `padding`...

```
  TextFormField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50, 38, 50, 10),
      filled: true,
      fillColor: Colors.blue,
      
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Você está usando um `contentpadding`, que por sua vez coloca "espaços" em cada lado...

Para que o texto comece no ínicio do seu *TextFormField*, basta diminuir o padding **LEFT**:

```
contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 38, 50, 10),
```

### Explicação

O *contentPadding* vai criar espaçamentos internos dentro do seu *Widget*, em relação ao conteúdo do mesmo, essa propriedade pede um `EdgeInsetsGeometry` que por sua vez você está utilizando o `fromLTRB`

Esse tipo significa:

```
EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(left, top, right, bottom)
```